# Converting Arabic Words to Unicode format in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I am designing an API where the API user needs Arabic text to be returned in Unicode format, to do so I tried the following:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToUnicodeString(this string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in str)
        {
            sb.Append("\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X4"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The issue with the above code that it returns the unicode of letters regardless of its position in word.

Example: let us assume we have the following word:

"سمير" which consists of:

'س' which is written like 'سـ' because it is the first letter in word.

'م' which is written like 'ـمـ' because it is in the middle of word.

'ي' which is written like 'ـيـ' because it is in the middle of word.

'ر' which is written like 'ـر' because it is last letter of word.

The above code returns unicode of { 'س', 'م' , 'ي' , 'ر'} which is:

> \u0633\u0645\u064A\u0631

instead of { 'سـ' , 'ـمـ' , 'ـيـ' , 'ـر'} which is

> \uFEB3\uFEE4\uFEF4\uFEAE

Any ideas on how to update code to get correct Unicode?

Helpful [link](http://www.wikizeroo.net/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvQXJhYmljX3NjcmlwdF9pbl9Vbmljb2Rl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Eric's answer I knew how to solve my problem, I have created a solution on [Github](https://github.com/yahya99223/C-Sharp-Arabic-Reshaper).

You will find a simple tool to run on Windows, and if you want to use the code in your projects then just copy paste `UnicodesTable.cs` and `Unshaper.cs`.

Basically you need a table of Unicodes for each Arabic letter then you can use something like the following extension method.

```
public static string GetUnShapedUnicode(this string original)
    {
        original = Regex.Unescape(original.Trim());
        var words = original.Split(' ');
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        var unicodesTable = UnicodesTable.GetArabicGliphes();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            string previous = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                string shapedUnicode = @"\u" + ((int)word[i]).ToString("X4");
                if (!unicodesTable.ContainsKey(shapedUnicode))
                {
                    builder.Append(shapedUnicode);
                    previous = null;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == 0 || previous == null)
                    {
                        builder.Append(unicodesTable[shapedUnicode][1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i == word.Length - 1)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previous) && unicodesTable[previous][4] == "2")
                            {
                                builder.Append(unicodesTable[shapedUnicode][0]);
                            }
                            else
                                builder.Append(unicodesTable[shapedUnicode][3]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bool previouChar = unicodesTable[previous][4] == "2";
                            if (previouChar)
                                builder.Append(unicodesTable[shapedUnicode][1]);
                            else
                                builder.Append(unicodesTable[shapedUnicode][2]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                previous = shapedUnicode;
            }
            if (words.ToList().IndexOf(word) != words.Length - 1)
                builder.Append(@"\u" + ((int)' ').ToString("X4"));
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The string is just a sequence of Unicode code points; it does not know the rules of Arabic. You're getting out exactly the data you put in; if you want different data out, then put different data in!

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\u0633\u0645\u064A\u0631");
Console.WriteLine("\u0633\u0645\u064A\u0631".ToUnicodeString());
Console.WriteLine("\uFEB3\uFEE4\uFEF4\uFEAE");
Console.WriteLine("\uFEB3\uFEE4\uFEF4\uFEAE".ToUnicodeString());
```

As expected the output is

```
سمير
\u0633\u0645\u064A\u0631
ﺳﻤﻴﺮ
\uFEB3\uFEE4\uFEF4\uFEAE
```

Those two sequences of Unicode code points render the same in the browser, but they're different sequences. If you want to write out the second sequence, then don't pass in the first sequence.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to convert a string to its glyph equivalent. For example, while `سلام` is 4 characters, when rendering, it will be rendered using 3 glyph `ﺳ`, `ﻼ`, `ﻢ`.

Comment: what I am expecting is \uFEB3\uFEE4\uFEF4\uFEAE when I pass "ﺳﻤﻴﺮ"  because \u0633\u0645\u064A\u0631 is the unicode of س م ي ر not ﺳﻤﻴﺮ
check the table here please http://www.wikizeroo.net/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvQXJhYmljX3NjcmlwdF9pbl9Vbmljb2Rl

Comment: @YahyaHussein: Your statement is simply false. The string "سمير" is \u0633\u0645\u064A\u0631, I promise. And the string ﺳﻤﻴﺮ is \uFEB3\uFEE4\uFEF4\uFEAE, honest. You can have multiple strings that *look* the same but have *different unicode code points*. The contents of the string are the contents of the string; how those look when they are rendered is up to the browser!

Comment: @YahyaHussein: Similarly, if you put the string `"ВАСКЅІЕЅ"` through your tool, you would get a different result than if you put `"BACKSIES"` through, because those are two *completely different strings*. (Try it! Cut-n-paste the strings from the comments and see what happens.) The fact that in some browsers they look the same is irrelevant. **How the characters are rendered does not matter, and lots of different characters look the same when rendered**.  The characters in the string are the ones in the string.

Comment: thank you for the clarifications, but I am still a bit confused, if I am building a browser, how would I know when to render a letter 'م' like 'م', 'مـ' , 'ـمـ' , or 'ـم' ?

Comment: @YahyaHussein: Well, you're an Arabic reader and a computer programmer, so you tell me: if you were tasked with that problem, how would you solve it? It's not magical; Microsoft hired a bunch of people with deep knowledge of Arabic script and a bunch of people with deep knowledge of code -- and many of them were of course experts in both -- and they wrote a *lot* of *extremely complicated* code.  Then that process was repeated for Greek and Cyrillic and German and Danish and Korean and Japanese and Thai and hey, software is expensive, but Windows is localized.

Comment: @YahyaHussein: Be happy you have Unicode and all the problems it creates, because when I started working on localization code in 1994, Windows 3.1 did not support Unicode. We had to have a build for Japan, and a build for China, and a build for Korea, and so on. And rather than a nice UTF-16 world where 99.99% of the characters you want are exactly 16 bits, we were in a world where some characters were 8 and some were 16. Oh, the bugs I had to fix in Korean Visual Basic. Kids today have it so easy.

Comment: @YahyaHussein: Of course, Arabic is particularly tricky because, unlike most languages it is read right-to-left, and as you note, it has an unusually rich set of rules for rendering letter forms depending on where in the word they are. Compare that to languages like Greek, where the rules are much simpler; for example, in Greek words that end in σ the sigma is written ς. But the browser does not attempt to enforce that rule; if you write "Phobos" incorrectly as Φόβοσ the rendering engine does not attempt to render the more correct Φόβος.

Comment: too much history in there :D, I know software is expensive, I was just trying to have a better understanding of my problem, thanks again!